# Can we be able to see contents of broker registry, consumer registry, ownership registry, and offset registry in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I just wanted to quickly check, how to check contents of broker registry, consumer registry, ownership registry and offset registry. is it possible to check contents of above registries, if yes, how ? if not why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the script `zookeeper-shell.sh` provided in the distribution to view the contents of the registry.

```
$ sh zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
ls /
[cluster, controller, controller_epoch, brokers, zookeeper, admin, isr_change_notification, consumers, config]
ls /brokers
[ids, topics, seqid]
ls /brokers/topics
[topic1, topic2, topic3]
ls /brokers/topics
get /brokers/topics/topic1/partitions/0/state
```

You can use `ls` or `get` command to list / view the contents of the registry stored in the zookeeper.